# Cant remove duplicate items in collection in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to remove duplicate items from a collection that I request via an API in Laravel.

This is my code:

```
computed: {
      // slice the array of data to display

      filteredList() {

        /* NEW PART */


            var tips = this.dublicate;

            /* END NEW PART */



          tips = this.items.filter(item => {
            return item.tip.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
          })
          return tips.slice(0, this.display);

      },

      dublicate() {

        var filtered_array = [];
        for(var i =0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
            if(this.items[i].tip.toLowerCase() != this.items[i+1].tip.toLowerCase()) {
              filtered_array.push(this.items[i])
            }
        }
        return filtered_array;
      }
   }
   }
```

If I remove the code within the NEW PART comments, everythin works fine.
In the `NEW PART` I am trying to remove duplicate content, based on the items `tip attribute`.
If the tip attribute is the same as the next items tip attribute, it should be excluded from the tips array, which is returned as a v-for="tips in filteredList".

**However, I just get an empty array with this new part. What am I doing wrong?**

I get the following from Vue Devtools:

```
dublicate:"(error during evaluation)"
filteredList:"(error during evaluation)"
```

An example data from items, that are from an API request:

[image]

(This is the data that I get, when I dont try to remove duplicates, which works)

As this is in VueJS, I cant use the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate values from JS array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array)

Comment: You're defining `tips` as a function, not as the result of a function call.

Comment: Hi @RoyJ I have updated my question, as this is now a result of a function call. Still not working though :/

Comment: Can you include a sample of data for `items`?

Comment: Oh, if `dublicate` is a computed, you can't call it as a function. The line should be `tips = this.duplicate`

Comment: Hi @RoyJ - Thanks for your input. Ive changed the function call to `this.duplicate`, and included some sample data in my question. However I still can not get it to work, and I get `(error during evaluation)`

Comment: If you are using something like Lodash, they have a `uniq()` that will return duplicate free arrays

Comment: `i + 1` goes beyond the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking past the end of the array with `i + 1`. You need to push the last item without looking for the one after it (because there isn't one). I think using `filter` is more straightforward than building an array with a `for` loop.

```
dublicate() {
  return this.items.filter((a, i) =>
    i === this.items.length - 1 ||
    a.tip.toLowerCase() !== this.items[i + 1].tip.toLowerCase()
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Roy, I will be testing tomorrow and will return with an acceptet answer if this works :) Thanks for your input and support!

Comment: Hi Roy, yep this worked right out of the box! Thank you! If you have time, I would like it if you could help me clarify some things about the code.
Im not entirely sure what the function does. The filter function has a & i, and a is the items? What does `i === 0 ||` mean? And the filter goes through all the items, and checks if a tip is not equal to the next, and then pushes it into the duplicate array that can then be used as a `v-for`, is the correctly understood?

Comment: `i` is the index, and `a` is the item. `i === 0` means you're looking at the first item.  It keeps each item that is not equal to the *previous* item. The test for zero is because there is no previous item for that one.

Comment: I have just updated the code to keep items that differ from the *next* item. If looking at the last item, it keeps it and does not try to look at item `i + 1` (due to `||` short-circuiting).